# Spring Boot @RestControllerAdvice not Catching Custom Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and I'm having trouble with exceptions. I want to use a `@RestControllerAdvice` class to catch exceptions at a global level. I am able to catch validation errors and return a custom error response, but Spring seems to be ignoring my `handlePhotoNotFoundException` method. Here is my `@RestControllerAdvice` class:

**DmsResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class DmsResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        
        ValidationErrorResponse response = new ValidationErrorResponse();
        response.setHasErrors(true);
        
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
            ValidationErrorModel errorModel = new ValidationErrorModel();
            errorModel.setFieldName(((FieldError) error).getField());
            errorModel.setRejectedValue(((FieldError) error).getRejectedValue());
            errorModel.setErrorMessage(error.getDefaultMessage());
            errorModel.setErrorCode(error.getCode());
            response.getErrors().add(errorModel);
        });
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(PhotoNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ApiErrorResponse handlePhotoNotFoundException(PhotoNotFoundException ex, HttpStatus status) {
        
        ApiErrorResponse apiError = new ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 404, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex.getMessage());

        return apiError;
    }
}
```

Here is the method where I am throwing the exception:

**PhotoStorageServiceImp.java**

```
@Override
public Resource getThumbnailPhotoByIndex(int index, Vehicle vehicle, DealerAccount account) {
    logger.info("LOADING THUMBNAIL!!");
    Photo photo = vehicle.getImages().stream().filter(image -> {
        return image.getIndexNumber() == index;
    }).findFirst().orElseGet(() -> new Photo());
    
    return loadPhotoAsResource(photo.getThumbnailFileName(), vehicle, account);
}

@Override
    public Resource loadPhotoAsResource(String fileName, Vehicle vehicle, DealerAccount account) throws PhotoNotFoundException {
        
        logger.info(fileName);
        logger.info(account.getId().toString());
        
        initDirectories(vehicle.getId(), account.getId());
        
        Path file = fileUploadDirectory.resolve(fileName).normalize();
        logger.info("file " + file.toString());

        Optional<Resource> optionalResource = Optional.empty();
        try {
            optionalResource = Optional.of(new UrlResource(file.toUri()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Resource resource = optionalResource.orElseThrow(() -> new PhotoNotFoundException("Photo not found!!!"));

        if(resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new PhotoNotFoundException("Error retrieving photo!!!");
        }
    }
```

**PhotoUploadController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/{fileName:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPhoto(
    @PathVariable String fileName, 
    @PathVariable Long vehicleId,
    @RequestParam("size") String size,
    HttpServletRequest request,
   @AuthenticationPrincipal DmsUserDetails dmsUser) {

Vehicle vehicle = vehicleService.findVehicleById(vehicleId);

Optional<Resource> optionalFile = Optional.empty();
Resource resource = null;

switch (size) {
case "thumbnail":
    resource = photoUploadService.getThumbnailPhotoByIndex(0, vehicle, dmsUser.getDealerAccount());
    break;
case "featured":
    optionalFile = photoUploadService.getFeaturedPhotoByIndex(0, vehicle, dmsUser.getDealerAccount());
    break;
case "gallery":
    optionalFile = photoUploadService.getGalleryPhotoByIndex(0, vehicle, dmsUser.getDealerAccount());
    break;
default: 
    
}
logger.info("file resource: " + fileName);



Resource file = optionalFile.orElseThrow(() -> new PhotoNotFoundException("Photo with filename ["+fileName+"] not found"));

// Try to determine file's content type
String contentType = null;
try {
    contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.info("Could not determine file type.");
}

// Fallback to the default content type if type could not be determined
if(contentType == null) {
    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
}

return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=\" + file.getFilename() + \"\\\"")
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
        .body(file);
```

}

I am getting the error `Error retrieving photo!!!` but with a stacktrace and the 500 error. For some reason, Spring is ignoring my `@ExceptionHandler` annotation in the `@RestControllerAdvice` class. What I would like to do is quietly log the error, return a message to the user that the image isn't available, then return a URL to a "image is missing" photo.

I'm very new to working with exceptions in Java, so help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here's the full stack track:

```
com.webbdealer.dms.main.exceptions.PhotoNotFoundException: Error retrieving photo!!!
    at com.webbdealer.dms.main.services.PhotoStorageServiceImp.loadPhotoAsResource(PhotoStorageServiceImp.java:177) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.webbdealer.dms.main.services.PhotoStorageServiceImp.getThumbnailPhotoByIndex(PhotoStorageServiceImp.java:188) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.webbdealer.dms.main.controllers.api.v1.PhotoUploadController.getPhoto(PhotoUploadController.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, I removed the `HttpStatus` from the method and it works!! Thank you so much for the help!

Now my error response is clean!

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: could you add the code of your @RestController method where you call your service ?

Comment: @CyrilG. I've edited my post and added my controller code and an additional method to the service class.

Comment: Please add stacktrace printStackTrace() , seems like your method throwing diffrent exception .

Comment: Can you give it a try without `, HttpStatus status` in the handle method? I've had issues like this because of extra parameters.

Comment: post full error stack trace

Comment: @Adarsh, thank you! I removed the `HttpStatus` and it now works! I would like to understand why, but I'm happy to move forward now!

Comment: @Adarsh, it looks like you used the comment section to answer the OP's question.  Please formally answer as an Answer so others can see...not to mention you will get the proper credit for it.

Comment: @TLangworthy Awesome that it worked. Added the comment as an answer with why this happens. To help other, do upvote and accept (if you think the reasoning helps you). Cheers!

Comment: @K.hervey Added as an answer

Comment: @Adarsh, Thanks.  I upvoted...I also looked for your contact info on your profile, but....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Exceptionhandler` method:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(PhotoNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public ApiErrorResponse handlePhotoNotFoundException(PhotoNotFoundException ex, HttpStatus status) 
{      
  ApiErrorResponse apiError = new ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 404, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex.getMessage());
 
  return apiError;
}
```

The parameter `HttpStatus status` is causing the issue. Remove this extra parameter.

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html), the allowed parameters are:

> - An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception. This also serves as a mapping hint if the
>   annotation itself does not narrow the exception types through its
>   value().
> - Request and/or response objects (typically from the Servlet API). You may choose any specific request/response type, e.g. ServletRequest
>   / HttpServletRequest.
> - Session object: typically HttpSession. An argument of this type will enforce the presence of a corresponding session. As a
>   consequence, such an argument will never be null. Note that session
>   access may not be thread-safe, in particular in a Servlet environment:
>   Consider switching the "synchronizeOnSession" flag to "true" if
>   multiple requests are allowed to access a session concurrently.
> - WebRequest or NativeWebRequest. Allows for generic request parameter access as well as request/session attribute access, without
>   ties to the native Servlet API.
> - Locale for the current request locale (determined by the most specific locale resolver available, i.e. the configured LocaleResolver
>   in a Servlet environment).
> - InputStream / Reader for access to the request's content. This will be the raw InputStream/Reader as exposed by the Servlet API.
> - OutputStream / Writer for generating the response's content. This will be the raw OutputStream/Writer as exposed by the Servlet API.
> - Model as an alternative to returning a model map from the handler method. Note that the provided model is not pre-populated with regular
>   model attributes and therefore always empty, as a convenience for
>   preparing the model for an exception-specific view.